# The trailing slash in home page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I will be really greatful if someone helps me with this.

Let's consider these 2 URLs (both returning 200 in the response header):

www.foo.com/something
www.foo.com/something/

Google considers these 2 URLs different despite both having the same content which leads to a duplicated content problem. To solve the issue it is advised to either use the 301 permanent redirect to redirect one URL to the other or use the `rel="canonical"` attribute. [source](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html)

Wordpress blogs deal perfectly with this matter. When adding the trailing slash to my internal links, I was redirected to URLs without the trailing slash (301 response).

The problem is the redirect is only happening with internal pages. My homepage seem to return a 200 response with or without the trailing slash. Should I leave it as it is or force a redirect with the `.htaccess` file?

p.s.: The backlinks to my website have 2 different hrefs (with and without the trailing slash). Should I change those backlinks to a unique href or redirect one to the other?

Answer (score 0):

Use [this link to add trailing slash to end of your url](http://www.mydigitallife.info/add-trailing-slash-to-the-end-of-the-url-with-htaccess-rewrite-rules/)

It doesn't matter whether your Backlinks are with slash or not, because after implementing techniques mentioned in above address, search engines will assume your pages only with slashes. Remember because of past indexing you should wait until former index to be deleted. or you may use 301 redirect to pages with slash. Basically this will take some time until search engines came again and find your redirect rules, too... .

Comment: Again, the rules in this link will make a 301 redirect from non-slash to slash links only in internal links witch can be achieved by changing the permalink settings in Wordpress to a custom structure like /%postname%/. I want to know if the Home Page (www.foo.com) needs a redirect to www.foo.com/.

Comment: Will the link juice will be passed by the Backlinks to each specific version (slash or no slash) or it will be passed to the version that the redirect is made to or it doesn't matter as both will receive the same link value?

Comment: Yes from Search engines point of view, both will receive the same link value.
 remember in most of situations, if you do something like /%postname%/ to link your pages these addresses without slash will load your contents,too.
 As i know for major search engines, www.foo.com and www.foo.com/ are the same.

Answer (score 0):

By home page I assume you mean the page shown when you enter just the domain.

With or without the slash represents exactly the same URL. Nothing to worry about and nothing you can do.